# How to install pip in RHEL6 to use "virualenv" with python 2.6.6

Tags: pip, virtualenv, python-2.6, rhel6

**Background:**

Robot scripts are developed on Python 3.* and they can only be executed in python3.

**Problem:**

We have RHEL6 machine which uses python 2.6.6 which cannot be updated.

**Prepared Solution :**

We are trying to enable the use of virtualenv in a RHEL6 machine so that we can execute the robot scripts in virtual environment with a different python version, We are facing issues with installation of pip in RHEL6 machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need `pip/setuptools` from here: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/ and you need a very old version of `virtualenv`.

Download `get-pip.py` and run

```
sudo python2.6 get-pip.py
```

[`virtualenv` 15.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/15.2.0/) seems to be the last version that supports Python 2.6. Try

```
python2.6 -m pip install 'virtualenv==15.2.0'
```

or

```
python2.6 -m pip install 'virtualenv<16.0'
```

with you fresh `pip`.

Comment: Unfortunately the pypa link is now dead. There is get-pip.py for 2.6 at https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.6/, but running it on RHEL 6.10 fails with: No matching distribution found for pip<10